# Change default css in extjs 4.2.1 CSS Variables

Tags: css, extjs4.2

everybody I am new in extjs. I am using extjs 4.2.1. and there is one new tab "CSS Vars" in ExtJS docs. but I can't set that variables config in normal way. Can anyone suggest me how to change default CSS behavior of extjs (4.2.1) using CSS vars ?

for example I want to set back-ground color of panel using $panel-body-background-color. then
how can I set in panel config ? I am getting error in following peace of code.

```
xtype:'panel',
border:true,
$panel-body-background-color : 'black'
```

Comment: i edited..but my question was not that. it gives error still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you will get everything you need to know how to use css variables and extjs themeing.
https://github.com/Scorpie/Ext.ux.BrowserCheck/blob/master/extjs-4.1.0/docs/guides/theming/README.md

Answer (score 0):

The CSS variables are not for use in this manner, they are used in the SASS process.  Check out the ExtJS docs for more info on how to use this: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/theming

Comment: Is there any way to apply CSS variables to one component without styling a whole application?

Comment: added it as a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256482/extjs-theming-single-component